# Sumar la Misma Columna en diferentes Tablas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buscando su apoyo para resolver una duda: Estoy buscando la forma de sumar una columna que se llama igual en diferentes Vistas que tengo en SQL Server, tengo el siguiente Query pero tarda bastante en hacer la operación. Existe una forma más efectiva para hacer dicha operación?

Gracias

```
SELECT
    CONCEPTO = 'Global Markets y Tesoreria',
    DIA_A = (SELECT (A.DIA_A + B.DIA_A + C.DIA_A + D.DIA_A + E.DIA_A + F.DIA_A) FROM VPNL_VENTASINST A, VPNL_TESORERIA B, VPNL_RATES C, VPNL_DERIVADOS D, VPNL_FX E, VPNL_CAPITALES F WHERE A.ID_PNLVENTASINST = 9 AND B.ID_PNLTESORERIA = 15 AND C.ID_PNLRATES = 3 AND D.ID_PNLDERIVADOS = 12 AND E.ID_PNLFX = 8 AND F.ID_PNLCAPITALES = 8),
    MES_A = (SELECT (A.MES_A + B.MES_A + C.MES_A + D.MES_A + E.MES_A + F.MES_A) FROM VPNL_VENTASINST A, VPNL_TESORERIA B, VPNL_RATES C, VPNL_DERIVADOS D, VPNL_FX E, VPNL_CAPITALES F WHERE A.ID_PNLVENTASINST = 9 AND B.ID_PNLTESORERIA = 15 AND C.ID_PNLRATES = 3 AND D.ID_PNLDERIVADOS = 12 AND E.ID_PNLFX = 8 AND F.ID_PNLCAPITALES = 8),
    ANO_A = (SELECT (A.ANO_A + B.ANO_A + C.ANO_A + D.ANO_A + E.ANO_A + F.ANO_A) FROM VPNL_VENTASINST A, VPNL_TESORERIA B, VPNL_RATES C, VPNL_DERIVADOS D, VPNL_FX E, VPNL_CAPITALES F WHERE A.ID_PNLVENTASINST = 9 AND B.ID_PNLTESORERIA = 15 AND C.ID_PNLRATES = 3 AND D.ID_PNLDERIVADOS = 12 AND E.ID_PNLFX = 8 AND F.ID_PNLCAPITALES = 8)
```

Este es el Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estás uniendo las tablas múltiples veces generando una combinación excesiva. Podrías generar algo más eficiente consultando cada tabla por separado y sumando las filas generadas usando `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT CONCEPTO = 'Global Markets y Tesoreria'
      ,DIA_A = SUM(DIA_A)
      ,MES_A = SUM(MES_A)
      ,ANO_A = SUM(ANO_A)
FROM (
    SELECT DIA_A, MES_A, ANO_A
    FROM VPNL_VENTASINST
    WHERE A.ID_PNLVENTASINST = 9
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DIA_A, MES_A, ANO_A
    FROM VPNL_TESORERIA 
    WHERE ID_PNLTESORERIA = 15
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DIA_A, MES_A, ANO_A
    FROM VPNL_RATES
    WHERE ID_PNLRATES = 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DIA_A, MES_A, ANO_A
    FROM VPNL_DERIVADOS
    WHERE ID_PNLDERIVADOS = 12
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DIA_A, MES_A, ANO_A
    FROM VPNL_FX
    WHERE ID_PNLFX = 8
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DIA_A, MES_A, ANO_A
    FROM VPNL_CAPITALES
    WHERE ID_PNLCAPITALES = 8)S;
```

Comment: Excelente! Gracias, se redujo el tiempo muchísimo y su rendimiento es más eficaz.